# Create timer queue in Linux using C++

Tags: c++, linux, timer, callback

I have implemented a project in Windows using C++ that creates a timer queue, add entries to it, perform a callback function when the timer expires,waits for next timer, etc. It was possible using the Windows functions `CreateTimer`, `CreateTimerQueueTimer`, `CreateTimer`,etc.

Now my question is how to do the same thing in Linux using C++? Is there some API ? Is `timer_create` a good option for doing this? It will be much helpful if an example is also provided.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use [libevent](http://libevent.org/) for this ?