# How to pass a callback function pointer to epoll_event structure in C++

Tags: c++, linux, timer, callback, epoll

I have been searching an answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407963/create-timer-queue-in-linux-using-c) and I came across the functions `timerfd_create` and `epoll`in Linux. In a tutorial it was said that `epoll_ctl()` has an `epoll_data_t` union member of the `epoll_event` structure which can be used to execute a `callback` function on a `timerfd` event firing. But I am not sure on how to do it. Can anyone please help.

Comment: Do you mean `epoll_wait` times out, or you have a `timerfd` that fires?

Comment: I have a timerfd that creates a timer and this timer expires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put a callback function pointer into `epoll_event` because it can't fit in any of these slots:

```
typedef union epoll_data {
    void        *ptr;
    int          fd;
    uint32_t     u32;
    uint64_t     u64;
} epoll_data_t;
```

What you could do instead is store the timer fd in the `epoll_event` and check to see if that's the one that fires:

```
epoll_event ev;
ev.data.fd = timerfd;

epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, timerfd, &ev);
```

With that setup, then when we call `epoll_wait`, we can check to see if the `event` that fired was for `timerfd`:

```
int n = epoll_wait (epollfd, events , num_events, -1 ); 
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (events[i].data.fd == timerfd) {
        handle_timer_callback();
    }
    else {
        // something else
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're open to giving up some performance, you can just create a complete object hierarchy for events:

```
class EventHandler {
public:
    virtual ~EventHandler() = default;
    virtual int fd() const = 0;
    virtual void fire() = 0;
};
```

You can store an `EventHandler*` into `ptr`:

```
EventHandler* handler = new TimerHandler();
ev.data.ptr = handler;
epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, handler->fd(), &ev);
```

And that way, if *everything* we put into `epoll` is an `EventHandler`:

```
int n = epoll_wait (epollfd, events , num_events, -1 ); 
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    static_cast<EventHandler*>(events[i].data.ptr)->fire();
}
```

Comment: Its not an epoll timeout.

Comment: I want to create a timer which on timeout should execute a function. I thought of executing this function as a callback function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But can you please give a minimal working example? I haven't used any of these functions till now and is a bit confused. Sorry if this need is useless..

Comment: @Jackz Uh, no. I'm not writing your entire project for you.

Comment: I was sorry to ask that. And I would like to ask you another doubt. Why is it that we have to declare both a variable and an array of `struct epoll_event` in the program?