# EPoll Callback function

Tags: linux, callback, signals, epoll

i have a question refering to the following topic: [How to pass a callback function pointer to epoll_event structure in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446631/how-to-pass-a-callback-function-pointer-to-epoll-event-structure-in-c/45687135#45687135)

I am using the example and try to replace the if/else-block with two callback functions for timer and signal. But I don't know how.

This is the part of my code:

```
    int n = epoll_wait (epollfd, events , num_events, -1 );
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (events[i].data.fd == timerfd) {
            read(....);
            printf ("Timer %....");
        }
        else if (events[i].data.fd == signalfd){
            read();
        }
    }
```